# Count no. of subsets with given sum

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve Count no. of subsets with given sum leetcode problem, my code is working fine for most of the test cases, but it's not handling cases where '0' occur in array.

eg : `arr[] :{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0}`, `sum: 1`

Here output should be `256`.

This is my code :

```
private int[][] dp;

/** nums => input array
    n => nums.length-1
    sum => target sum
**/
public int findNoOfSubset(int[] nums, int n, int sum) {
    //System.out.println(n  +" " + sum);
    if(sum == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    
    if(n < 0 || sum < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    if(dp[n][sum] != -1) {
        return dp[n][sum];
    }
        
    if(sum >= nums[n]) {
        return dp[n][sum] = findNoOfSubset(nums, n-1, sum-nums[n]) + findNoOfSubset(nums, n-1, sum);
    }
    
    return dp[n][sum] = findNoOfSubset(nums, n-1, sum);
}
```

Can somebody guide me how to handle 0 element cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake, just posting the solution in case anyone face the same problem.

```
public int findNoOfSubset(int[] nums, int n, int sum) {
    if(sum == 0 && n<0){
        return 1;
    }
    
    if(n < 0 || sum < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    if(dp[n][sum] != -1) {
        return dp[n][sum];
    }
        
    if(sum >= nums[n]) {
        return dp[n][sum] = findNoOfSubset(nums, n-1, sum-nums[n]) + findNoOfSubset(nums, n-1, sum);
    }
    
    return dp[n][sum] = findNoOfSubset(nums, n-1, sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A different way to look at this problem can be to find the number of ways the sum of a subset can be found.

```
// Create a map with key as the sum of a subset and value as the number of ways this sum was found.
Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<>(); 
// initialising as 0 can be found by selecting no numbers 
primary.put(0,0);
for (Integer i : numbers) {
  List<Integer> newSums = new ArrayList<>();
  for (Integer possibleSum : m.keySet()) {
        if (i+possibleSum > targetSum)
          continue;
        newSums.add(i+possibleSum);
  }
  for (Integer newPossibleSum : newSums) {
        m.put(newPossibleSum, m.getOrDefault(newPossibleSum, 0)+1);
  } 
}
return m.getOrDefault(targetSum,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int getSubsetwithsumk(int arr[], int n, int k) {
    int t[n+1][k+1];
    //initialisation
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n + 1 ; i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < k + 1 ; j++){
            if(i == 0){
                t[i][j] = 0;
            }
            if(j == 0){
                t[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 1 ; i < n + 1 ; i++){
        for(int j = 1 ; j < k + 1 ; j++){
            if(arr[i-1] <= j)
              t[i][j] = t[i-1][j - arr[i-1]] + t[i-1][j];
            else{
                t[i][j] = t[i-1][j];
            }  
        }
    }
    return t[n][k];
    
}
```